# Specific downloable content for specific user

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api

I want to make system on my wordpress site which allows specific users download specific content for a certain period of time.

Let's say I purchased some device through woocommerce. And for the next two years I have access to download software updates that will appear on the site for the next year.

I don't know how to do this, but I found that woocommerce has its own REST API, but I don't know how I can combine it with my idea.

Do you have any ideas or can you help me in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Create product and select Downloadable and add files..after user purchase product user can download files from my account section

Comment: It wouldn't work because any person could go in at any time and download that file without any verification. And I want to do it in such a way that the person, after buying the device, had access for two years to the software updates that will be added on the website.